# How do i reset the forgotten password of glassfish server 4

Tags: glassfish-4, password-recovery

Recently, i change the password for admin, and unfortunately i don't remember the password of my glassfish server 4. How, can i reset the    password.

I've followed the instruction provided in the following link "https://superuser.com/questions/7654/how-to-reset-delete-my-glassfish-password", but it didn't help me.

i went to this path "../glassfish4/glassfish/domains/MyDomain/config/" and change the "admin-keyfile" file, but still it didn't help me.

Answer (score 25):

Finally, after few hours of posting the question, i found a solution.
On my glassfish installed directory, this in my case `/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/mydomain/config`. I edit the file named with file name `admin-keyfile`. 
i added this line next to the existing line( but i commented the existing line).

`admin;{SSHA}WQVj8i9CLECCiv+w6ZxGgMrcfPqHPoXZW+2Jdw==;asadmin`

Then i restart the glassfish server.

Since, i m loading the glassfish server in different machine[Not required if running locally], i additionally need to run this command `asadmin enable-secure-admin` to make secure enable and `asadmin change-admin-password`. To set new password. Then i restarted the server again.
Finally it worked.

Comment: Once the above commands are executed. asadmin change-admin-password will ask for old password after giving in username. Just press enter and giving new password for next question. new login should work..

Comment: Some More Steps                                                                                               
     $ ./asadmin 

         $ change-master-password --savemasterpassword  // default password is chageit  

       $ change-admin-password    // default password is blank and admin user 
  name is admin

       $ start-domain

$ wget http://localhost:8080/

$ enable-secure-admin

$ restart-domain

Answer (score 0):

For me creating a new domain and replacing old domain's keyfile with the new one worked.

My glassfish version 2.1.1 and OS is windows server

1. stop your glass domain (eg for domain name : domain1)

```
asadmin stop-domain domain1
```

2. backup .asadminpass (only required if you had savemasterpassword enabled) and admin-keyfile

```
move /Users/your_username/.asadminpass to  .asadminpass_bkup
move {glassfishpath}/domains/domain1/config/admin-keyfile to  admin-keyfile_bkup
```

3. create a new domain and fill in the username with what you had in your original domain. probably admin

```
 asadmin create-domain --adminport 4848 domain2
```

4. copy new domain's admin-keyfile to old domain

```
copy {glassfishpath}/domains/domain2/config/admin-keyfile to {glassfishpath}/domains/domain1/config/admin-keyfile
```

5. Start your server

```
asadmin start-domain domain1
```

Voilla now your domain1's password is changed to the password you inserted when creating domain2