# What is the default username and password for the administration console of the payara full app server when booted from the official docker image?

Tags: docker, jakarta-ee, configuration, glassfish, payara

I'm using the official docker image for payara full, the 5.183 version, here is my [setup](https://github.com/ninrod/kotlin-angular-jakarta-ee/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).

I've tried admin/blank, admin/admin, admin/changeit, nothing works.

I could not find any documentation on the payara site about this and the blogs I've found related to this did not help.

[image: console admin login page]

Comment: Have you checked the [references](https://github.com/ninrod/kotlin-angular-jakarta-ee#references) section on that page, that seems to be helpful. Especially the part where it links to `configuring payara’s master password`

Comment: yes, In fact, I've written that information. That's my repo. That link has information that does not work, I've just tried with this script: https://github.com/ninrod/kotlin-angular-jakarta-ee/tree/master/img/custom_payara

Comment: ah, have you tried admin/newpassword pair in case the script may have worked ?

Comment: that's the problem. the script cannot build the image. after the change password command, it errors out on me with: "No server instances in directory /opt/payara5/glassfish/nodes/payaradomain"

Answer (score 3):

The credentials for all Payara Server docker images are admin/admin for the username and password. You can find this out in the README in the GitHub repositories (also available in [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/payara/server-full/)):

https://github.com/payara/docker-payaraserver-full/blob/5.183/README.md

> ...the admin interface is secured by default (in both the default domain1 as well as payaradomain), accessible using HTTPS on the host machine: https://localhost:4848 ***The default user and password is admin.***

You can also see this is the case from the actual Dockerfile at line 34:
https://github.com/payara/docker-payaraserver-full/blob/5.183/Dockerfile#L34

> ENV ADMIN_PASSWORD admin

If this isn't working for you, then something else is probably going on.

I tested this myself using `docker run -it -p 4848:4848 payara/server-full:5.183` and found I could log in with admin/admin. For reference, here is the exact image I was using:

```
REPOSITORY            TAG       IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
payara/server-full    5.183     b216dd970898        3 months ago        973MB
```

Check that your ID matches to verify that it is the same image.

Comment: **Note**: I added this as an answer rather than a comment thread because, while it may not solve your problem, it is an answer to the question asked. Hopefully I included enough supplementary information to help you find the solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in a similar situation - the difference was that it wasn't a docker image - I had only to execute `asadmin change-admin-password` from the `...\payara-5.2020.5\glassfish\bin` folder and when prompted for the current admin password (eg. "Enter the admin password>") just leave blank and continue with the next steps of setting it.

So, basically, what I have learnt from this is that the password is not yet set and you have to use the CLI to set it before using the console.

Note: I have taken the summary above from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41079590/2407369). You may also check if the full scenario from there fits you better.